# Clearcase - Get latest version of a file undependent of branch

Tags: clearcase, config, specifications

Is there a way to make a config spec, to get the latest version of all files?
What i really want to do is to look at the date of each file, and take the file wich was most recently modified. (Even if it is checkedout / reserved)

(I want to use this to make a snapshot-view, and be sure that i always have the latest files. Im aware of that it can cause problems where i have parallell branches, but it's okay for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `/LATEST` rule is enough to select the last version.

For a given branch:

```
 element * .../aBranch/LATEST
 element * /main/LATEST
```

Now, you cannot select the most recent version of an element amongst *several* branches: you must pick one branch first.

For *one* file, you could first determine which branch contains the most recent version, by parsing the result of "**[`cleartool lshistory`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm)**".
But that approach doesn't scale well when you have thousands of files.